# Why is my program returning result AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to make a weather app. I am using this code

```
def getWeather():
    city = textfield.get

    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
    location = geolocator.geocode(city)
    obj = TimezoneFinder()
    result = obj.timezone_at(lng = location.longitude,lat = location.latitude)
    print(result)
```

I was attempting to input a city and get where the city. Instead i get the afformentioned error. Ty for any help

Comment: `location` is `None`, so `geolocator.geocode(city)` is returning `None`. You might be getting wrong the value of `city`.

Comment: That would depend on what `textfield.get` is - it seems like it is a method/function - i.e. not a textual value as you'd expect.

Comment: You need to call the `get` method: `textfield.get()`